# What is the equivalent of document.location.pathname in angular's $location?

Tags: angularjs, url

There is a mismatch between `document.location.pathname` and `$location.path()`.

I have an angular SPA running out of something like `http://myhost.com/services/coolstuff`.

When you navigate to that location, I have some router rules to navigate you to something like: `http://myhost.com/services/coolstuff#/users/1`.

At this point, you can call  `$location.path()` and it will give you `/users/1`. And `document.location.pathname` gives you `/services/coolstuff`.

Is there a mechanism to retrieve the actual URL path from `$location`? I don't want the Angular hash path (`/users/1`), but the actual URL path (`/services/coolstuff`). How can I get that?

Comment: `$document.location.pathname`?

Comment: That's using native location object. I'm looking to use the angular `$location` object.

Comment: Well, it doesn't provide that information.

Comment: All right...that's unfortunate. I guess I'll have to go native. If you convert your comments into an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party here, but the [parsing section of the URL specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-parsing) is very specific about this (and super tedious to read...):

The gist of the above specification is, that an unencoded `#` character denoted the start of the `URL fragment`, which is not part of the `path`.

This essentially means, that `$location.path()` behaves differently from what the URL specification defines. An implementation compliant with the spec has to return `/services/coolstuff` as `document.location.pathname` consequently does.

In general, if something is supported in native JS, I would always opt for that, since you can be sure (as you see from your example) that browser implementations adhere to the specified standards which is often not the case for third party libraries.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, `$location.path()` is behaving correctly according to what angularJS needs to do. It must support browsers that don't use the history API. So, the angular "path" is just the path-like part of the fragment. And I am using native now. The reason that I wanted to use an AngularJS API is that it would have been easier to unit test.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Thanks for the hint, I rephrased my answer to make it clearer that it's not per se "wrong", but rather simply deviating from the spec!